# Configuring AirPlay to play video on apple tv for AVPlayer while app goes in background

Tags: ios, avplayer, nativescript, airplay

Referring to the document https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1668/_index.html ,
I have modified the info.plist to support playback for HLS stream while app is in background, and removed/restored AVPlayer when app goes to background/comes to foreground using Application delegate events(application: app didBecomeActive and application: app didEnterBackground) , am certain that code gets executed as I can see the logs. Yet when I navigate out of the app by pressing home key on actual device, Airplay stops. Also, I added a KVObserver on the rate property of AVPlayer, the rate is 1 while the app is minimized.
 One thing that I noticed was for the same piece of code, on simulator, If I simulate home key press (cmd+shift+h) , the audio for the video is audible while I am outside the app, while it stops on actual device. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Had to put the methods :

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate: self];    
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
```

in the app delegate, thought they were just for audio streaming, but for video as well are required for multitasking, this resolved the issue.

Comment: You can leave out the first line where you set the delegate as it's now deprecated in iOS 10. Also, the simulator isn't reliable for testing so you should use an actual device. I would also make sure that in the Project Settings -> Capabilities -> Background Modes that you check the box for the first item "Audio, Airplay, and Picture in Picture"